# PostGIS Intermittent INDEX Performance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index

I have a table containing approximately 55 million data points ( point is a geometry with SRID 4326 ) and for my query I need to join this to an area table ( currently have ~1800 areas ) which contains a variety of different ranging from large polygons ( 2000 km square ) to fairly small ( small being about 100 km square ).

The initial query selected by the user narrows down the initial 55 million points to around ~300,000 points dependent on date range etc they select. Then the join is done and dependent on what area set they have selected to use once the query is complete this normally narrows it down to a ~150,000.

The problem I'm having is that some times the query just grinds to a halt and instead of taking the expected ~25 seconds it can take up to ~18 minutes. At this point have to usually do a VACUUM ANALYSE and then run a few queries before it starts behaving itself again. No data has been added, updated or removed from the data or areas tables at this point.

I've played around with everything I can think of and this still seems to keep happening with no constancy too it. Both the data.point column and the area.polygon column have GIST INDEXES on them.

I found removing the INDEX from the data.point column seemed to make things a bit more stable but is slower ~35 seconds normally. However removing an INDEX seems to be a very bad choice as should it not be helping not hindering?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.4 with PostGIS 1.5

Here's the query I'm running

```
    select * FROM data, area WHERE st_intersects (data.point, area.polygon) AND 
(readingdatetime BETWEEN '1948-01-01' AND '2012-11-19') AND datasetid IN(3) AND
 "polysetID" = 1 AND area.id IN(28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11)
```

EXPLAIN

```
Nested Loop  (cost=312.28..336.59 rows=5 width=2246) (actual time=1445.973..11557.824 rows=12723 loops=1)
  Join Filter: _st_intersects(data.point, area.polygon)
  ->  Index Scan using "area_polysetID_index" on area  (cost=0.00..20.04 rows=1 width=1949) (actual time=0.017..0.229 rows=35 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("polysetID" = 1)
        Filter: (id = ANY ('{28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11}'::integer[]))
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on data  (cost=312.28..316.29 rows=1 width=297) (actual time=328.771..329.136 rows=641 loops=35)
        Recheck Cond: ((point && area.polygon) AND (datasetid = 3))"
        Filter: ((readingdatetime >= '1948-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (readingdatetime <= '2012-11-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=312.28..312.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=328.472..328.472 rows=0 loops=35)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on data_point_index  (cost=0.00..24.47 rows=276 width=0) (actual time=307.115..307.115 rows=1365770 loops=35)
                    Index Cond: (point && area.polygon)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on data_datasetid_index  (cost=0.00..284.37 rows=12856 width=0) (actual time=1.522..1.522 rows=19486 loops=35)
                    Index Cond: (datasetid = 3)
Total runtime: 11560.879 ms
```

My create tables

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  datasetid integer NOT NULL,
  readingdatetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  value double precision NOT NULL,
  description character varying(255),
  point geometry,
  CONSTRAINT "DATAPRIMARYKEY" PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_point CHECK (st_ndims(point) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_point CHECK (geometrytype(point) = 'POINT'::text OR point IS NULL),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_point CHECK (st_srid(point) = 4326)
);

CREATE INDEX data_datasetid_index ON data USING btree (datasetid);
ALTER TABLE data CLUSTER ON data_datasetid_index;

CREATE INDEX "data_datasetid_readingDatetime_index" ON data USING btree (datasetid , readingdatetime );
CREATE INDEX data_point_index ON data USING gist (point);

CREATE INDEX "data_readingDatetime_index" ON data USING btree (readingdatetime );

CREATE TABLE area
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  polygon geometry,
  "polysetID" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT area_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id )
)

CREATE INDEX area_polygon_index ON area USING gist (polygon);
CREATE INDEX "area_polysetID_index" ON area USING btree ("polysetID");
ALTER TABLE area CLUSTER ON "area_polysetID_index";
```

Hope that all makes a degree of sense if need to know anything else please ask.

Short summary is really that the INDEXES seem to work some times but not others.

Could anyone suggest anything I could try to work out what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Another example

```
select * FROM data, area WHERE st_intersects ( data.point, area.polygon) AND 
(readingdatetime BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2012-01-19') AND datasetid IN(1,3) AND
 "polysetID" = 1 AND area.id IN(28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11)
```

Run on copy of table with point index

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1153.60 rows=35 width=2246) (actual time=86835.883..803363.979 rows=767 loops=1)
  Join Filter: _st_intersects(data.point, area.polygon)
  ->  Index Scan using "area_polysetID_index" on area  (cost=0.00..20.04 rows=1 width=1949) (actual time=0.021..16.287 rows=35 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("polysetID" = 1)
        Filter: (id = ANY ('{28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11}'::integer[]))
  ->  Index Scan using data_point_index on data  (cost=0.00..1133.30 rows=1 width=297) (actual time=17202.126..22952.706 rows=33 loops=35)
        Index Cond: (point && area.polygon)
        Filter: ((readingdatetime >= '2009-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (readingdatetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datasetid = ANY ('{1,3}'::integer[])))
Total runtime: 803364.120 ms
```

Run on copy of table without point index

```
Nested Loop  (cost=2576.91..284972.54 rows=34 width=2246) (actual time=181.478..235.608 rows=767 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((data_new2.point && area.polygon) AND _st_intersects(data_new2.point, area.polygon))
  ->  Index Scan using "area_polysetID_index" on area  (cost=0.00..20.04 rows=1 width=1949) (actual time=0.149..0.196 rows=35 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("polysetID" = 1)
        Filter: (id = ANY ('{28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11}'::integer[]))
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on data_new2  (cost=2576.91..261072.36 rows=90972 width=297) (actual time=4.808..5.599 rows=2247 loops=35)
        Recheck Cond: ((datasetid = ANY ('{1,3}'::integer[])) AND (readingdatetime >= '2009-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (readingdatetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "data_new2_datasetid_readingDatetime_index"  (cost=0.00..2554.16 rows=90972 width=0) (actual time=4.605..4.605 rows=2247 loops=35)
              Index Cond: ((datasetid = ANY ('{1,3}'::integer[])) AND (readingdatetime >= '2009-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (readingdatetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Total runtime: 235.723 ms
```

As you can see the query is significantly slower when the point index is being used.

EDIT 2 ( Pauls Suggested Query ):

```
WITH polys AS (
  SELECT * FROM area
  WHERE "polysetID" = 1 AND area.id IN(28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11)
)
SELECT * 
FROM polys JOIN data ON ST_Intersects(data.point, polys.polygon)
WHERE datasetid IN(1,3) 
AND (readingdatetime BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2012-01-19');
```

EXPLAIN

```
Nested Loop  (cost=20.04..1155.43 rows=1 width=899) (actual time=16691.374..279065.402 rows=767 loops=1)
  Join Filter: _st_intersects(data.point, polys.polygon)
  CTE polys
    ->  Index Scan using "area_polysetID_index" on area  (cost=0.00..20.04 rows=1 width=1949) (actual time=0.016..0.182 rows=35 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ("polysetID" = 1)
          Filter: (id = ANY ('{28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11}'::integer[]))
  ->  CTE Scan on polys  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=602) (actual time=0.020..0.358 rows=35 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using data_point_index on data  (cost=0.00..1135.11 rows=1 width=297) (actual time=6369.327..7973.201 rows=33 loops=35)
        Index Cond: (point && polys.polygon)
        Filter: ((datasetid = ANY ('{1,3}'::integer[])) AND (readingdatetime >= '2009-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (readingdatetime <= '2012-01-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Total runtime: 279065.540 ms
```

Comment: You talk about "the query" as if it's exactly the same SQL every time. Is it?

Comment: In addition to what Paul has said above, how about posting the results of an EXPLAIN of the query? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: @PaulRamsey No the query isn't the same each time, as I said its dependant on inputs the user selects. However I didn't bog my question down with that as it doesn’t make a difference what those filters are, well it does it just affects it in the way you would expect if there is less rows due to tight constraints its faster and vice versa. But it gets affected the same way as in it can some times start running really slow till doing the VACCUM ANALYSE as I explain above, no matter what the query is.

Comment: @Kelso Sorry forgot to add that I'll add an EXPLAIN very shortly.

Comment: Have added an EXPLAIN and a few other bits.

Comment: @MarkDavidson if the query is not *exactly* the same then it does make a difference. For example: say the user chooses 10 values of area.id for the ANY condition and then chooses 30. The planner could switch to a different strategy because table statistics tell it it is best to do so.

Sometimes (worst case scenarios) the difference could be triggered by adding just one more value to a condition.

Comment: Had a similar problem, involving the use of `ST_DWithin(3)`, tweaking the query to use `ST_Within(2)` instead resulted in enhanced planning stability.

Answer (score 4):

Effectively forcing the planner to do the thing you want might help. In this case, sub-setting the polygon table *prior* to executing the spatial join with the points table. You might be able to outwit the planner using "WITH" syntax:

```
WITH polys AS (
  SELECT * FROM area
  WHERE area.id in IN(28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11)
)
SELECT * 
FROM polys JOIN data ON ST_Intersects(data.point, polys.polygon)
WHERE datasetid IN(3) 
AND (readingdatetime BETWEEN '1948-01-01' AND '2012-11-19');
```

The trouble with trying to play these games is that you are coding into your statement the assumption "my polygon list will always be more selective than my other query portions". Which might not be true for all parameterizations of your query, or for all applications of a particular query over a heterogeneously distributed dataset.

But it might work.

**UPDATE**: This goes even further down the dangerous road of assuming you know the selectivity of your clauses beforehand, this time we also take the attribute selection on the point table out and do it separately before the spatial join:

```
WITH polys AS (
  SELECT * FROM area
  WHERE area.id in IN(28,29,30,31,32,33,25,26,27,18,19,20,21,12,13,14,15,16,17,34,35,1,2,3,4,5,6,22,23,24,7,8,9,10,11)
),
WITH points AS (
  SELECT * FROM data
  WHERE datasetid IN(3) 
  AND (readingdatetime BETWEEN '1948-01-01' AND '2012-11-19')
)
SELECT * 
FROM polys JOIN points ON ST_Intersects(points, polys.polygon);
```

Comment: Updated my question with your suggested query and the EXPLAIN result paul. Does seem to perform better but still no where near as good as without the index. I am looking at the query and wondering though is it to do with the fact that its trying to work out if all points are in the polygons before its narrowing down the readingdatetime and datasets or am I misunderstanding the EXPLAIN?

Comment: Can you clarify what table readingdatetime and datasetid come from?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it in the DDL. The problem is now pretty clear, I think, and it's down to the join selectivity coming back way too selective. I hadn't noticed that your other clauses are subsetting the point table. Push the non-spatial filters up into a WITH clause as well.

Comment: This is looking very promising paul after pushing the rest of the non-spatial queries up into the WITH clause. I've been off work ill for the last 2 days so haven't had chance to 100% confirm that its solving the issue, but I'm going to award you the bounty as all your advise both here and on the [postgis-users](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2012-November/035788.html) list has been very helpful. Will report back once I know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the explain for the *Run on copy of table with point index* on the first EDIT it looks like you're missing this index on the table without point index:

```
CREATE INDEX "data_readingDatetime_index" ON data USING btree (readingdatetime );
```

Can you confirm that the index is there?

-- EDIT --

After some more studying of your question (not an easy one, btw) I have the following suggestions to make.

1. drop the "data_datasetid_readingDatetime_index" index as you have already indexed the two columns separately. This will save you space, improve insert performance and will simplify query planner job by taking one variable out of the equation
2. cluster the table agains the "data_readingDatetime_index" index. Clustering is more effective with range-based queries. You don't seem to query datasetid with range-based conditions

   ```
   ALTER TABLE data CLUSTER ON data_readingDatetime_index;
   ```
3. Perform the actual clustering. The command at the previous item does not cluster your table, it merely expresses your desire that if the table were to be clustered, you wanted it to be clustered on that index. Cluster it with:

   ```
    CLUSTER data;
   ```
4. analyze the table after clustering it so that statistics (used by the planner to decide which strategy to choose) note the new layout on disk:

   ```
    VACUUM ANALYZE data;
   ```

   now since the data is organized against readingdatetime the planner will favor a strategy where the data_readingDatetime_index index is used and since whenever it is used the explain plan seems to be the fastest then perhaps performance will improve and fluctuate less

As I said in the comment to Paul answer above, do not think that the planner will not change strategy depending on the filters (even if the filters are always the same and only their values change).

There is an example in the highly recommended [PostregSQL 9.0 High Performance book](http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book) where changing a condition from *select ... from table t where v<5* to *v<6* switched the plan from index scan to full table scan.

Comment: If you look at his third explain, you'll see "        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "data_new2_datasetid_readingDatetime_index"  (cost=0.00..2554.16 rows=90972 width=0) (actual time=4.605..4.605 rows=2247 loops=35)" which is where the index on that column actually comes into play once the spatial index is taken out of the equation.

Comment: exactly my point. it's there in the fast query, not in the slow one (the slow one being the one in the explain plan before the third one you mention). Could it be that in copying the table the index got lost?

Comment: No, as noted above, the planner is skipping that index in favor of the spatial one, because the spatial one is (incorrectly) reporting a very high selectivity to the planner. So it exists, it's not being used.

Comment: @unicoletti Thank you very much for your input will certainly give you suggestions a go and will report back on the results soon. I've actually got the 
PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance book totally agree highly recommend reading know I need to read it more myself to make sure get every little performance boost I can.